# How to Display image using Opengl ES with shader language in IOS.?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I had implemented the code for display image using Opengl ES with Shader in IOS.

Steps follwed:

1.Created Context.

2.Created shader and compiled.

3.Linked shader

4.Loaded image as Texture.

linking Opengl ES with shader for Texture.

```
GLuint  _fishTexture = [self setupTexture:@"test-1bit-alpha.png"];
    GLuint  _texCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(program, "TexCoordIn");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);
    GLuint    _textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Texture");

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // unneccc in practice
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fishTexture);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0); // unnecc in practice
    const char *aPositionCString = [@"a_position" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    GLuint aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, aPositionCString);
     glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));
```

My vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position; 
attribute vec2 TexCoordIn; // New
varying vec2 TexCoordOut; // New

void main(void) {
   // DestinationColor = SourceColor;
    gl_Position = a_position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn; // New
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut; // New
uniform sampler2D Texture; // New

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut); // New
}
```

I had build successfully, but I did not get display image.

How to display image using opengl es with shader.?

Did u give any sample code for display image using Opengl ES with shader.?

Comment: The code you posted seems good, there can be other issues though. First try to dispaly only some color to see if the quad is in the right place for you to see (just modify the shader to output a static color instead of texture) Then try checking the texture coordinates by modifying the shader to use X for red and Y for blue on the color output and see if you get a nice 2D gradient with red and blue color. Other most common issues are missing texture parameters for magnification, minification... Also check if your texture is loaded correctly...